# how to determine the number of numbers in a text file in C

Tags: c

I'm reading a text file of numbers and I want to get the sum of this number, how can I determine the number of numbers in the text file."my text file is consist of one line"

this is the code I have written, how to determine number of numbers in the text file to put it instead of the variable "number of numbers" in the secondline of code

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    int integers[number of numbers];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int num;

    while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) {
        integers[i] =num;
        printf("%d",integers[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    int sum=0;
    for(j=0;j<sizeof(integers)/sizeof(int);j++)
    {
        sum=sum+integers[j];
    }

    printf("%d",sum);
    printf("\n");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To do that, you'd need to read the file once, count the lines, close it, reopen (or seek to the beginning) and read it all again. Have you considered, instead, keeping track of the sum as you're reading and printing each number? No reason to store them and compute the sum later.

Comment: Everything Paul said, sans-counting lines. There is no reason to do even that. Each successfully invoked `scanf()` (you should check the return result of that, btw) will be one more number to add to you "number of numbers" accumulator, and along with that, the accumulted sum. The array is useless for the task of obtaining the number of numbers and their sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need individual numbers but only the sum of all of them, what you should do is just add them together at the same time as you read them:

```
int sum = 0;
int num;
while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) {
    sum += num;
    printf("%d",num);
    printf("\n");
}
```

On the other hand, if you really need to keep every single number, you can do it different ways.

- You could first read the file while counting the numbers, then seek to the beginning, allocate the needed memory and read again saving each number.
- You can ask for some memory at first, and when you run out (you are going to have to keep track of how many free spaces you have) ask for more memory (`realloc`), and keep doing that until you are finished.
- You can use a linked list instead of an array, if you didn't need random access.

**Edit:**
If for some case you need to do an avarage, and thus you really need the total amount of numbers you read, just declare a `int n = 0;` and inside the loop do `++n;` so you have it in the end.

Comment: `++n; sum += num;` and `printf("%d\n", num)` is probably what you were going for, where `n` is the number of numbers, `sum` is their accumulated summation, and `num` is the just-read number.

Comment: Yes, it is, let me fix it, sorry. Fixed it. Made such a mess of a simple answer lol.

Comment: Now that's definitely better.

Comment: And... still missing the number-of-numbers counter increment.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not sure if that's really needed if you don't want to store the numbers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why do you even need the number of numbers? He wanted it to preallocate, it's not needed if you just sum everything, is it?

Comment: @H2CO3 It is about to become needed when that OP moves to part (b) of his assignment, namely "Find the *average*" =P. But I concur, for summation only, its totally *not* needed.

Comment: Ok, I hope you don't have any more complaints!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this, there are three possible solutions:

1. make `integers` quite large (say 10000 elements) and say "Too many numbers" if there are more than the "quite large" number.
2. Read the file twice, count the number of numbers the first time, second time store them.
3. Use dynamic allocation, and start with a small number, when that number is reached use `realloc` to allocate a larger array, until all numbers have been read.

However, in your particular case, what you are doing can be done without at all storing the numbers. So, the whole `integers` array is completely unnecessary.

Just do:

```
 sum += num;
```

in the first loop.

Answer (score 4):

First, figure out if you actually need to save every number. Quite frequently it is possible to do simple data processing by computing some intermediate result without needing to keep every input. For example, it is possible to compute the mean and standard deviation of an input set without keeping the input dataset.

In your specific example, you can print every number as it is read, then accumulate them into `sum`, without having to keep all of them.

If you decide you really need to keep every number, then you have two options:

1. Read through the file once to count the number of numbers, then allocate the array, then `fseek` back to the beginning to read all of them.
2. Allocate an initial array, then use `realloc` to progressively increase its size (in this case, make sure to increase the size by a fixed factor when needed, rather than just increasing the size by one).